# Can ASM hook android.graphics.BitmapFactory?

Tags: java, android, android-gradle-plugin, hook

I wrote a TraceFixMethodTracer that inherits ClassVisitor. The android.graphics.BitmapFactory is not printed in the visit method, but all my app-related classes are printed.

```
public void visit(int version, int access, String name, String signature,
                      String superName, String[] interfaces) {
        System.out.println("TraceFixClassVisitor : visit -----> started : " + name);
        super.visit(version, access, name, signature, superName, interfaces);
        this.mClassName = name.replace("/", ".");
        if ((access & Opcodes.ACC_ABSTRACT) > 0 || (access & Opcodes.ACC_INTERFACE) > 0) {
            this.isABSClass = true;
        }
        mCollectedClassExtendMap.put(mClassName, superName);
        mInterfaces = interfaces;
    }
```

I want to add Log in decodestream